# how to change this hill cipher encryption script to execute char 8 bits (.txt)?

Tags: matlab, encryption, cryptography

I have a hill cipher encryption script to execute **image**. But I want this to be a script to execute **char 8 bits (.txt)**. Please help me, thank you :)

```
I=imread('E:\Lena.bmp');
I=rgb2gray(I);
I2=I(:);
n=size(I2);
K=[2 5;3 12];
d=mod(det(K),256);

if(d==0)
    disp('determinant should not be 0');
  return
end
if(gcd(d,256)>1)
    disp('determinant should be coprime integers with 256');
  return
end

%encryption process
for i=(1:2:n)
    x=[I2(i);I2(i+1)];
    x=mod(K*double(x),256);
    CI(i)=x(1);
    CI(i+1)=x(2);
end

I3=reshape(CI,[256 256]);
I3=uint8(I3);
imshow(I3)
imwrite(I3,'encryption.bmp','bmp');
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following answer does not comment on the encryption method itself but only  on how to get the needed input and how to process the output.**

*The only thing:* The line defining the for-loop should be `i=(1:2:n-1)`. Note that you need to use `n-1` because later you try to access `I2(i+1)` and in Matlab the first index is `1`.

---

The output of `rgb2gray` is of type `uint8`. So basically what we need is to read the text file with `fscanf` and then convert `char` to `uint8`. Now the format of `I` is the same as you would use an image as input.

```
F = fopen('data.txt','r');
D = fscanf(F,'%c');
fclose(F);
I = uint8(D);
```

After the encryption process, we can write the data back into a file with `fprintf` after converting to `uint8` and `char`.

```
F = fopen('data_encrypted.txt','w');
fprintf(F,'%c',char(uint8(CI)));
fclose(F);
```

Comment: but there is an error in `fprintf (F, '% c', char (uint8 (CI)));` which says  Undefined function or variable 'CI' @Matt

Comment: @Naufal Then your input `I` is most likely empty. You can initialize `CI` with `CI =[]` before processing, so the error does not occur anymore. Check if the read-in from the file works as expected.